# The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/MasterPages/Default.cshtml": "Title"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am getting error of Render section following is the stack trace of error.
i have cross checked in "Default.cshtml" page and i found the render section is optional still i am getting this error.

Default.cshtml:

```
<title>@RenderSection("Title",required: false)</title>
```

StackTrace:

```
    System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase : VerifyRenderedBodyOrSections The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/MasterPages/Default.cshtml": "Title".    at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.VerifyRenderedBodyOrSections()
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext()
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.<>c__DisplayClass7.<RenderPageCore>b__6(TextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result)
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body)
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext()
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
       at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
       at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17()
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19()
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
       at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
       at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()

   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Please suggest me where i am doing wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error is specifically being caused by a view defining the section, i.e.:

```
@section Title { ... }
```

But, the section is never utilized. That can only mean that this particular view is not utilize your `Default.cshtml` layout, as it does implement this section. You'll need to figure out why it's not utilizing the layout you think it should be. Here's a few things to look for:

1. Unless, you specifically set a layout in the view, the layout it uses will be determined by the closest `_ViewStart.cshtml` file. Razor will first look in the same folder as the view in question and then walk up the `Views` directory tree from there. Check any and all `_ViewStart.cshtml` files in that tree.
2. If you're utilizing layout inheritance, you must remember to redefine sections in each layout. For example, if you were to do something like the following:

   **Default.cshtml**

   ```
   @RenderSection("Title", required: false)
   ```

   **SubLayout.cshtml**

   ```
   @{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Default.cshtml"; }
   ```

   **View.cshtml**

   ```
   @{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/SubLayout.cshtml"; }
   @section Title { ... }
   ```

   You would get this error as `SubLayout.cshtml` does not implement that section. To redefine it, you would just need to add the following to `SubLayout.cshtml`:

   ```
   @section Title
   {
       RenderSection("Title", required: false)
   }
   ```

Comment: i have not use _viewStart.cshtml and adding layout on every page and section Title. but i found a partial view where Section Title is mentioned as its partial i am not using Layout. so please suggest me that may this cause problem and generate this issue.